# 10 Minute Timerbar Css3 Animation timing

Tags: css, animation

There are issues with the completion time with this css3 timer bar. On a recent test with mozilla, it worked well. However, on an ipad it's about 25 seconds slow. My next attempt will be to add more @keyframe percentages. However, the tests take 10 minutes long each time so it's ideal to ask here first.

```
    .timerbar {
      height: 60px;
      width: 100%;
      background: #484949;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 500;
    }
    .shrinking{
        width: 100%;
        height: 60px;   
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        /*activate the 3D rendering engine.*/

    /*    animation: fillBar 1s ease-in infinite; */
        -webkit-animation-name: fillBar;
            animation-name: fillBar;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 600s;
                animation-duration: 600s;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
                animation-timing-function: linear;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
                animation-iteration-count: 1;
        -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
                animation-direction: normal;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #1B676B, #519548);  
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fillBar {
          0% {
            width: 100%;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
                -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
          }
          100% {
            width: 0%;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
                -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
          }
      }
      @keyframes fillBar {
          0% {
            width: 100%;
                animation-timing-function: linear;
                animation-direction: normal;
          }
          100% {
            width: 0%;
                animation-timing-function: linear;
                animation-direction: normal;
          }
      }
```

Both normalize and modernizer are installed. This code is being run on a rails project. The cache is cleared on each test.

Comment: I reccomend using javascript for advanced animations and timings you have far better control try looking at the greensock librarytimeline max is a very good for this kind of thing.

Comment: yeah the more I think about it, doing the whole thing in javascript might be a better route. But I thought I'd try to tackle the css3 for the experience first.